# Undefined symbol in trying to install data.table package for R version 4.3.1 in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: r, data.table, undefined-symbol

Trying to install data.table package in Ubuntu 22.04 for R 4.3.1  but still cannot go past this error:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘data.table’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
> unable to load shared object '/home//R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/00LOCK-data.table/00new/data.table/libs/data_table.so':
> /home/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/00LOCK-data.table/00new/data.table/libs/data_table.so: undefined symbol: brl_deflateReset
> Error: loading failed

Tried direct install via R command prompt and via RStudio with compilation. Is "undefined symbol: brl_deflateReset" related to ZLib in some way? I have ZLib nd its dev packages installed. gcc version 11.4.0

Comment: It certainly looks related to zlib. I'm on ubuntu-22.04.3 with gcc-11.4.0, `zlib1g:amd64` and `zlib1g-dev:amd64` (both `1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu9.2`), and using CRAN's default repo I was able to `install.packages("data.table")` (compiling from source) without error on the R-4.3.2 console. I suggest making sure your `00LOCK*` dirs are cleaned out, then perhaps restart R and try again. Maybe force a reinstall of the `zlib1g` packages? If that also fails, you might want to install the binary package from Posit's https://packagemanager.rstudio.com (though the underlying problem is unfixed).

Comment: Thanx for help! I reinstalled zlib1g-dev but to no avail, apparently removing it removed a lot of other libs. Then I downloaded and installed newest zlib 1.3.1 and that worked. Package DescTools (and its dependency data.table) were installed .

Comment: Glad you got it to work! If you need to find what packages were _uninstalled_ on that attempt, you can look in `/var/log/apt/history.log` and reinstall (as needed). I was actually recommending forcing a reinstall (and not two remove/reinstall steps), but it is not unrecoverable.